# Dynamic Carousel slider HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am busy building a local website that needs a dynamic carousel. I currently have a static one that i have made. So it needs to read all images from a local folder, so if theres new images i dont need to manipulate the html to add them in. Could you guys please help? Will appreciate if you could give me a source for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with JavaScript as it does not have access to a computer's file system. That is because JavaScript was designed with security in mind.

You need to use server side languages for this like asp or PHP. You would be able to access the filesystem then with the correct security permissions and build your Java Script array code on the server. When the page loads up the paths to your images will exist in the web page and then you can do what you want with them in your Java Script.

JavaScript can't directly access the contents of a file system. You'll have to pass the contents using a server-side script (written in PHP, etc) first.

Then once you have that, you can use a loop in your JavaScript to load them individually.

A possible solution would be to use the [File API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) but you still need to give permission.

**OR check this out as an example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
    slideSpeed: 100,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="sidebar col-sm-4">
      <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      
      <!-- HERE you can fetch all image from folder by using Server Side Languages for this like asp or PHP & loop through the results -->
      
        <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x300?text=image1" alt="The Last of us"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x300?text=image2" alt="GTA V"></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x300?text=image3" alt="Mirror Edge"></div>
        
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!--row-->

</div>
<!--container-->
```